# Mi input autocomplete no funciona bien

Tags: laravel, ajax, input, jquery-ui, autocomplete

```
<form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0 position-relative" autocomplete="on">
     <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 sec border-primary placeholder-white text-white" type="text" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Search" id="search" autocomplete="on">
     <button class="btn text-primary my-2 my-sm-0" style="margin-left: -50px;" type="submit"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Este es mi formulario para hacer un buscador, estoy utilizando ajax.
Este es el código:

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{route('buscar.servicio')}}",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data);
                    console.log(data[0].nombre);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Estoy utilizando jqeury-ui y si funciona la consulta de los datos, ya que utilizo un `console.log` para mostrar los datos y si los muestra, pero algo anda mas en mi input, no muestra los datos del autocomplete.

Muestra esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por que sale una barra blanca envés del resultado?? y como lo soluciono??
Lo que muestra la consola es el resultado de la BD

Comment: ¿Responde [esta pregunta](/questions/247518/como-hacer-un-autocomplete-a-un-input-con-ajax) tu duda?

Answer (score -1):

Has probado el elemento datalist?

```xml
<form ...>
    <input list="datalist-id" type="text" ...>
    <button ...>
        <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
    </button>

    <datalist id="datalist-id">
        // llenar con ajax
        <option value="valor 1"></option>
        <option value="valor 2"></option>
        <option value="valor 3"></option>
        <option value="valor 4"></option>
    </datalist>
</form>
```

Comment: Esta respuesta creo que debe ir mas como comentario

Comment: Puede ser, pero en un comentario no me cabía el ejemplo.

Comment: ¿Por qué preguntar "Has probado el elemento datalist?" y un fragmento de html respondería la pregunta de OP?

Comment: Porque quiere un input con autocompletado dado por un listado predefinido.